# Can I use this "hydro" inverter with solar panels SMA hyroboy HB 1124

Tags: solar-power, solar, hydrogen-fuel

https://files.sma.de/downloads/HB1124-TEN093421.pdf

Im assuming the inverter does not know where the DC current is coming from as long as it is below the maximum current, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, but you need to look at `V_DCmax`, `V_DC` and `I_DCmax` specs of your unit. If you exceed any of these with your solar panel, for example due to open circuit voltage exceeding `V_DCmax`, it won't work.

Also minimum input voltage may matter, for example the specs say 22 - 55 V voltage during operation is the permissible range. So don't try to use it with panels intended for charging 12V batteries (unless you connect two of them in series).

I would however heavily recommend a maximum power point tracking inverter that's intended for solar systems. Usually your limitation is how many panels you can fit on the roof, and if this is the case, MPPT offers you 20% more energy production for the same panel count.

So unless you already have the "hydro boy", don't order it, order something more suitable. But if you already have it, it's worth trying.